# Concatenate two videos recorded with Snapz Pro

Tags: imovie, encoding, quicktime

I've recorded two videos with Snapz Pro, and I'd like to concatenate them (i.e., have one immediately follow the other in a single file). What's the easiest way to do that? I have iMovie '08 installed, and I can use it to combine the two into a single movie. However, I can't get it to export the resulting video at the same resolution as the original video.

According to the QuickTime player inspector, the video formats of the two original videos are "Apple Animation, 1164x1153, Millions IMA 4:1, Mono, 22.050 kHz', FPS: 9.97 fps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have QuickTime 7 Pro, this is as easy as copy and paste.

- Open both videos in QuickTime
- Select and copy the contents of one video
  (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,
  <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
- Switch to the other video and move the playhead to the desired insertion point (e.g. the beginning or end) and paste (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

Then you can save the combined movie.

Of course, it is likely you don't already have QuickTime 7 Pro already installed. Apple charge extra for QuickTime Pro (£20) which may not be worthwhile for you if you don't use it much. Also, if you are using Snow Leopard, that includes QuickTime X which doesn't have a Pro version available. In that case you'd need to install QuickTime 7 in addition to QuickTime X.

I imagine there has to be a way to do it with iMovie as well, but I don't have experience with that. Perhaps someone else might.

Comment: The exact sequence above ended up prepending the second video instead of appending it, but otherwise it worked perfectly!

Comment: Good point, I revised to mention the insertion point.

Answer (score 2):

Becuase Apple Animation is an older QuickTime format, you should give QuickTime Player 7 a try, which has basic editing capabilities. If you're on Snow Leopard, it may not be installed, but you can [fix that pretty quickly](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3678)

If you need more than what QuickTime Player provides, it might be worth looking at [QuickTime Pro](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D3380Z/A).